# Problemas con permisos al usar la funcion tempnam() php

Tags: php, ftp

Estoy creando un pdf en un directorio temporal con la funcion tempnam
De la siguiente manera:

```
 $tmpfname=tempnam("/tmp","argprocesor");
file_put_contents($tmpfname.".rtf", $pdf);

exec("unoconv -f pdf ".$tmpfname.".rtf");

header("Pragma:");
header("Cache-control: private");
//header("Content-Type: text/rtf");
//header("Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=archivoTemporal.pdf");
```

Para luego ser enviado a un ftp con:

```
ftp_put($id,$directorio,$tmpfname,FTP_BINARY);
```

El problema es que la funcion tempnam no me permite hacer el envio ya que al crear el directorio temporal lo crea con permisos 0666. Ya intente cambiarle los permisos con:

```
chmod($tmpfname,0777);
```

Pero no los cambia al imprimir los permisos despues de poner esta linea de codigo igualmente la variable $tmpfname sigue teniendo permisos 0666 por lo que no me deja enviar el archivo por ftp.

Comment: ¿Qué valor devuelve chmod: TRUE o FALSE?

Comment: Acabo de imprimir lo que devuelve..... y Devuelve true.